# Finding Tools/scripts/ subdirectory

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Does anyone know where I could find [this](http://coverage.livinglogic.de/Tools/scripts/diff.py.html) file on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my machine it's in:

```
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/examples/Tools/scripts/diff.py
```

However, it'll vary a little depending on your distrib and how up to date you are. But there's a really handy little tool called 'locate' that you can use to quickly find stuff on your machine.

```
locate diff.py | grep Tools
```

Gives me

```
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/examples/Tools/scripts/diff.py
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/examples/Tools/scripts/ndiff.py
/usr/share/doc/python3.1/examples/Tools/scripts/diff.py
/usr/share/doc/python3.1/examples/Tools/scripts/ndiff.py
```

As I have two versions of Python installed. I put it through grep, as sometimes locate can match quite a lot.

If you're sure that you have a file on your machine, but locate isn't finding it, you might need to update your database, which is done with the 'updatedb' command, as root. So, just run

```
sudo updatedb
```

and get a coffee (or two if you have a slow machine/very full drive) and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

This command

```
  $ locate "Tools/scripts/diff.py"
```

will find the location of the file if it's installed. This depends on the database generated regularly by the `updatedb` command (this usually runs as a cron job, but can also be invoked manually)

FWIW, I just checked my Ubuntu installation (10.04LTS) and didn't find it. Perhaps only Python versions 2.7+ have this (the default version that came with this install is still v2.6.5)

Comment: he's wants to know the location of `diff.py` on ubuntu, this files comes with the python installation.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Apparently not with *every* Python installation, I don't have it on my Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to know this for a different environment, namely Linux running an Amazon Machine Image (AMI). I installed Python 3.5 via "yum" but couldn't find the Tools/scripts directory using find/locate, etc., or any other "yum" package which included it.

So in the end I cloned the python source tree mirror:

```
git clone https://github.com/python-git/python python
```

This downloads the Tools/scripts folder which I then moved to some standard location. I needed the "2to3" program from "scripts" and this worked. There is also a "clone or download" link at that URL where the package can be downloaded in the usual way if git is not available.

I couldn't find an easy way to install the Tools/scripts via "yum" on AMI Linux, which would still be my preference.